# How to clean up C++ compiler commands?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, compilation, magick++

I tried searching for a question like this as best as I could, but I simply don't know how exactly to ask the question. I apologize if this has been answered before, or if it is a trivial question. I am new to the large (and quite intimidating!) world of C++. I will try my best in the future.

Let me try to explain what I mean:

I am on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. On Ubuntu, to compile a C++ program I wrote, for example, let's say some file myProgram.cpp, I cd to its directory and type the following into the terminal:

```
g++ myProgram.cpp -o myProgram
```

This way, I can then type:

```
./myProgram
```

To run myProgram. This was simple and satisfactory -- and I learned this from reading the C++ Primer. After finding myself comfortable coding in C++, I decided to move onto giving myself a project, which involved using Image Magick, specifically, its C++ API: Magick++. However, now, if I wish to compile something, I have to type this ugly mess:

```
g++ `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags` -o testMagick testMagick.cpp `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
```

To make my code compile and execute. This seems very messy, and when I was trying to see if CImg was any better, it turned out that it needed its own set of arguments like `-lm`, `-lpthread` and `-lX11`. It also turned out that to compile with C++11, I had to write `-std=c++0x`. So my question is:

Is there a way to simplify/clean up my compile statements in the terminal, or do I have to find out and use a specific set of arguments whenever I compile a different kind of program using a different API?

Comment: Research "makefiles", maybe "cmake" and even "C++ IDE linux"

Comment: paddy, below has suggested the same about make files. I"ll look into them as my next step! Thank you!

Comment: You may want to look at a "build" tool such as "CMake" (http://www.cmake.org/) or "Ninja" (https://martine.github.io/ninja/) or "Scons" (http://www.scons.org/). CMake in particular can generate Makefiles for you or it can generate project files for IDEs and it makes cross-platform dev a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pinch, you can just make a shell script to execute this for you.  That lets you separate the clutter out:

```
#!/bin/bash
IMAPI_OPTS=$(Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags)
IMAPI_LIBS=$(Magick++-config --ldflags --libs)

g++ $IMAPI_OPTS -o testMagick testMagick.cpp $IMAPI_LIBS
```

You could call this file `build.sh`, and make it executable.  Then, just typing `./build.sh` would do the build the same way each time.

This isn't too far off what a Makefile would look like, however, and using a Makefile may be better for you in the long run.  The simplest Makefile that behaves like the above, and performs no dependency checks is:

```
IMAPI_OPTS=`Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags`
IMAPI_LIBS=`Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`

all:
        g++ $(IMAPI_OPTS) -o testMagick testMagick.cpp $(IMAPI_LIBS)
```

In this case, you just save it to the file called `Makefile`, and run `make` to do your build.

If you are interested to know more, try this link: [GNU make: Introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction)

Comment: Ah. So is it correct to think that for each kind of project I am using that will require different compilation statements, I would have to make a respective build.sh or MakeFile for each to get around to quick compilation?

Comment: Yes, it's best to keep your project sources in separate directories, and provide a build script for each.  Makefile is more common than a custom build script because it will abort on errors, and can manage dependencies etc.  Getting used to Makefiles will help you understand other projects and even other build systems similar to GNU make.  Here's a [link to a simple Makefile template](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) you can use as a starting point when you have projects with multiple source files.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'm kind of disappointed that there is no way to just have one nice statement to type into the terminal each and every time, but then again, I think that's asking for too much. I'll look into make files, especially since I know of them superficially and how they are essential to compiling large projects which would otherwise take a very long time. Thanks again, you've helped a newbie.

Comment: Ahh, well you see there *IS* a nice statement you type into the terminal each time: `make`. =)  You just need this tiny bit of wiring to make it go.